# Regular Expression need for the string Permanent Address : Fata colony | warsaw | road | Party : PTI

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Need to know the regular expression in python to split this:

> Permanent Address : Fata colony | warsaw | road | Party : PTI

into this list:

> [Permanent Address : Fata colony warsaw road, Party:PTI]

Comment: No it will not replace according to condition i want

Comment: check "|" is replaced by "," after the "road" @Rakesh

Comment: @SharjeelAliShaukat Can you add what you have tried to your question.

Comment: @SharjeelAliShaukat do you want this string to be converted into list based on '|' sign?? so if that is the case then the output should be something like 
[Permanent Address : Fata colony, warsaw ,road, Party:PTI]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do this with regex than you can use:

```
import re
str = "Permanent Address : Fata colony | warsaw | road | Party : PTI"
print(re.sub("\|\s(?=.*\|\s)","",str).replace(" |",","))
```

Comment: Does it work when `str = "Permanent Address : Fata colony | warsaw | road | Party : PTI | PPP"` ?

Answer (score 3):

I know OP is asking for a regular expression answer. But I don't know regex so well. Here's another solution to assist (since no answer has been given since the last 5 days).

```
my_str = 'Permanent Address : Fata colony | warsaw | road | Party : PTI'

final_list = []
items = my_str.split(':')
for i, sep in enumerate(items):
    if i == 0:
        # only adds key to the list (in first iteration)
        next_key = sep
        final_list.append(next_key)
    elif i == len(items) - 1:
        ''' Checks if it is the last split(:) element ('PTI' in this case) and appends everything to the last item in final_list'''
        split2 = sep.split('|')
        prev_val = ''.join(split2)
        final_list[i-1] += ': ' + prev_val
    else:
        ''' Excluding last item (from split(|)), appends everything else to the previous item of final_list'''
        split2 = sep.split('|')
        prev_val = ''.join(split2[:-1])
        final_list[i-1] += ': ' + prev_val
        next_key = split2[-1]
        final_list.append(next_key)

print(final_list)
```

I hope this helps